# Python - Count duplicates and sort by occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'project_id': ['61477', '61477', '3432', '3432', '3432'],
          'conf.type': ['k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend']
})
```

It looks like this (there are 15 columns in total, I only show 2):

```
        project_id     conf.type
0       61477          k-vison-trend
1       61477          k-vison-trend
2       3432           k-vison-trend
3       3432           k-vison-trend
4       3432           k-vison-trend
```

I want to count the number of duplicate 'project_id's but I don't want to drop them. I want to create different dataframes based on the count of duplicate 'project_id's. If the 'project_id' occurs:

- 1 or 2 times, place the row in df1
- 3 or 4 times, place the row in df2
- 5 or 6 times, place the row in df3
- 7 or 8 times, place the row in df4
- 9 times or more, place the row in df5

I already tried to group on the 'project_id' and use the size function to count the number of times a 'project_id' occurred, like this:

```
df.groupby('project_id').size().reset_index(name='count')
```

This gave me wrong output, for example: I expected output of 2 for the project_id of 61477 but got 3268 which is unlikely.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want `project_id`'s with 8 occurrences to appear two different places ?

Comment: I used the `groupby` code provided by you but I still got the correct number of occurrences for `61477`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby()` and `count()` to get the occurrences. Merge this with the original dataframe to keep the intial number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'project_id': ['61477', '61477', '3432', '3432', '3432'],
    'conf.type': ['k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend', 'k-vison-trend']
})

counts = df.groupby('project_id').count()

output_df = df.merge(counts, on="project_id")

output_df >>>
  project_id    conf.type_x  conf.type_y
0      61477  k-vison-trend            2
1      61477  k-vison-trend            2
2       3432  k-vison-trend            3
3       3432  k-vison-trend            3
4       3432  k-vison-trend            3
```

If you like you can filter based on the merged column `conf.type_y` and assign the results to new dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for your response, appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding your question correct, but try the following. The `dfs` object will contain a dataframe with the project_ids for each count interval.

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'1-2': [],
    '3-4' : [],
    '5-6' : [],
    '7-8' : [],
    '9+'  : []}
counts = Counter(df['project_id'])
print(counts)
for project_id in counts:
    count = counts[project_id]
    if count < 3:
        d['1-2'].append(project_id)
    elif 2 < count < 5:
        d['3-4'].append(project_id)
    elif 4 < count < 7:
        d['5-6'].append(project_id)
    elif 6 < count < 9:
        d['7-8'].append(project_id)
    else:
        d['9+'].append(project_id)

print(d)

dfs = []
for interval in d:
    dfs.append(df[df['project_id'].isin(d[interval])])

dfs[0]
```

Output:

```
    project_id  conf.type
0   61477   k-vison-trend
1   61477   k-vison-trend
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, appreciate it! :)